# Convert Timestamp with GMT to Timestamp in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe like this

```
df = [['1', '2019-12-13T15:15:52.786+05:30'], ['2', '2019-12-16T12:19:32.251+05:30']]
pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['ID', 'Timestamp'])

    ID  Timestamp
0   1   2019-12-13T15:15:52.786+05:30
1   2   2019-12-16T12:19:32.251+05:30
```

I want to extract datetime. I want to perform this operation on million+ records

Expected Output

```
    ID  Timestamp                       New_Timestamp
  0 1   2019-12-13T15:15:52.786+05:30   2019-12-13 15:15:52
  1 2   2019-12-16T12:19:32.251+05:30   2019-12-16 12:19:32
```

When I used `to_datetime` with `infer_datetime_format=True` it gives me an output like this

```
2019-12-13 15:15:52.786000+05:30
2019-12-16 12:19:32.251000+05:30
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```py
>>> df.Timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.Timestamp)
>>> df["New_Timestamp"] = df.Timestamp.dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
>>> df
  ID                        Timestamp        New_Timestamp
0  1 2019-12-13 15:15:52.786000+05:30  2019-12-13 15:15:52
1  2 2019-12-16 12:19:32.251000+05:30  2019-12-16 12:19:32
```

**Update**

You can also try `regex`

```py
>>> df = [['1', '2019-12-13T15:15:52.786+05:30'], ['2', '2019-12-16T12:19:32.251+05:30']]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['ID', 'Timestamp'])
>>> df.dtypes
ID           object
Timestamp    object
dtype: object
>>> df.Timestamp.str.replace(r'T',' ').str.replace(r'\..*','')
0    2019-12-13 15:15:52
1    2019-12-16 12:19:32
Name: Timestamp, dtype: object
```

Comment: pd.to_datetime runs very slow, because I have millions of records

Comment: Timestamp is of type object, so have to convert that into str first

Comment: `str` will be shown as `dtype` `object`. I don't think you need to convert to `str`

Comment: I need to, I tried it gave me an error, need to run astype first, which again is an expensive operation

Comment: when you convert the `str` to `datetime` then it will have `dtype` = `Timestamp    datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(330)]`

Comment: so what is the dtype of your dataframe. I tested with your example and it works fine for me

Comment: dtype is object

Comment: I have posted the entire repl output.

Comment: do I need to run to_datetime with infer schema = True?

Comment: if you don't want to convert the column to datetime type you don't have to call `to_datetime`

Answer (score 0):

This already has a datetime value, so using regular expressions can be inefficient.

so, if you want to delete the decimal point, try the following:

```py
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])
df['Timestamp'] = df['Timestamp'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(microsecond=0))
print(df)
```

```
  ID                 Timestamp
0  1 2019-12-13 15:15:52+05:30
1  2 2019-12-16 12:19:32+05:30
```

And discard the already set timezone and set your new timetimezone.

```py
df['Timestamp'] = df['Timestamp'].dt.tz_convert(None)
print(df)
```

```
0   2019-12-13 09:45:52
1   2019-12-16 06:49:32
Name: Timestamp, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

I hope this helps.